# Vue component use jQuery inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, trumbowyg

I am new to Vue and I don't really understand how I can work with jQuery (or even plain js) inside a component.

I have a component `component_1.vue` which has a form inside:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <textarea v-model="article.content" id="contentInput"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now I want to use a js textarea layout ([Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/)) to this textarea. How can I get this to work?

Even if I run `console.log(document.getElementById('contentInput'));` inside the `created()` lifecycle hook, it returns `null`. The check for jQuery inside the `created()` hook returns `JQUERY`, so jQuery is defined. I don't get any errors printed into the console.

This is the part of my js:

```
export default {
    props: {
        id: Number
    },
    data() {
        return {
            article: [],
        }
    },
    components: {},
    created() {
        this.fetchArticle();
        if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
            console.log('NOT');
        } else {
            console.log('JQUERY');
        }
        console.log(document.getElementById('contentInput'));
        $('#contentInput').trumbowyg({
            // TRUMBOWYG CONFIGURATION
        });
    },
    methods: {
        fetchArticle() {
            //FETCH ARTICLE FROM DB VIA AXIOS
        },
    }
}
```

How can I access the html, so that I can work with something like trumbowyg?

Comment: you should use `mounted()` method because at this point your component is rendered and mounted on DOM after that you can use jquery  to manipulate the DOM

Comment: this doens't change it. I still get `null` from the console.log()

Comment: There is a [Vue ported version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-trumbowyg) of this library.

Comment: Thats nice to know, Thanks! But is it normal that `console.log(document.getElementById('contentInput'));` returns `null`?  `console.log($('#contentInput').length);` returns 0. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you try assigning a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on this element? With this, you should never need to query the element via `document` object anymore.

Comment: The `mounted()` hook only means that the elements have been created, but they are not necessarily inserted into the DOM at this point. You should use `ref="myRef"` on the element and `this.$refs.myRef` in the `mounted()` hook to get the element reference.